# What is it called when you use screws with a butt joint?

Tags: joinery, butt-joint

I always thought that this wasn't done, because the screw would likely blow out, unless it's perfectly aligned.

I'm wondering if there's a name for this technique (using screws to reinforce a butt joint), and if there's a jig or technique for drilling the holes?

For example, cross-sectional view:

```
screw               __   _______________ 
[\\\\\\>   --->    |  | |_______________  board 2
                   |  |
                   |  |
                  board 1
```

I saw some guy doing this by hand (with no jig or drill press) in [the second half of this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObCLdiD2w5U).  Seems a little risky.  Is this common?

I've found something called a doweling jig, seems like it would work if used on `board 2`, but I don't think it would hold them both in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that particular video, the guy is working with particle board.  There is no grain structure in particle board (or MDF for that matter), so there really isn't a 'good' way to make a butt joint.

[image]

The screws that are used in most particle board construction are specialty 'confimat' screw (as listed [here on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0031TGSB2)).  These screws have very wide threads and are better in these types of material than more traditional screws.

Standard dowels would provide a much stronger joint.  The dowel forms a strong mechanical bond, and glue will hold the dowel in much tighter than the threads will hold a screw.  [Here](https://www.woodmagazine.com/woodworking-tips/techniques/joinery/dowel) is a good overview article on using dowels

[image]

Another option is to use a cross dowel.  These are often used for knockdown furniture, as it can be removed and reused with little if any loss of strength.  [Here](https://www.woodpeck.com/crossdoweljig.html) is jig that will allow both holes necessary for the cross dowel.

Answer (score 2):

A pocket drill jig will allow you to drill holes at an angle to board 2 into board 2 and engaging board 1.

[image: pocket drill jig]

The jig guides the drill into the work, which would otherwise skip off due to the extreme angle and also provides for a clean "pluggable" hole if desired.

This is mostly the opposite of what you ask, but a doweling jig is the answer to your question. Screwing into end grain is not going to provide a very strong joint.